# Visifire point chart with only one color

Tags: c#, charts, visifire

I'm trying to plot some data using a visifire point chart, but instead of having rainbow colors I just want one single color, or maybe if I add another dataset, do a different color for each dataset I am plotting.  Here is what I have so far.

```
ColorSet ct = new ColorSet();
ct.Id = "MyColorSet";
ct.Brushes.Add(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));

// Create a Chart element
Chart chart = new Chart();

//Create new instance of ColorSets class
chart.ColorSets = new ColorSets();
chart.ColorSets.Add(ct);
chart.ScrollingEnabled = false;
chart.AnimatedUpdate = true;

            // Set chart width and height
            chart.Width = 1400;
            chart.Height = 400;
            chart.ZoomingEnabled = true;

            // Create new DataSeries
            DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries();
            dataSeries.RenderAs = RenderAs.Point;
            dataSeries.MarkerType = MarkerTypes.Triangle;
            dataSeries.MarkerSize = 3.5;

            // Loop and add a few DataPoints
            for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < numOfPoints; loopIndex++)
            {
                // Create a DataPoint
                DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint();

                // Set the YValue using random number
                dataPoint.YValue = arr[loopIndex].mass;
                dataPoint.XValue = arr[loopIndex].num;
                // Add DataPoint to DataSeries
                dataSeries.DataPoints.Add(dataPoint);
            }

            // Add DataSeries to Chart
            chart.Series.Add(dataSeries);

            // Add chart to the LayoutRoot for display
            ChartGrid.Children.Add(chart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
 System.Windows.Media.Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkRed);
 dataSeries.Color = brush;
```